# Как пройтись по всем маршрутам?

Tags: php

Добавляю маршруты в массив вот так:

```
public function addRoute($method, $route) {
   $this->routes[$method][] = $route;
}

public function dispatch () {
  // вот как тут пройтись по всем маршрутам?
}

//index.php
addRoute('GET', new Route('', 'home@index'); // Route - request, path
```

Comment: А в чем сложность. Есть же цикл foreach, к примеру

Comment: вы спрашиваете как в php сделать цикл по массиву?

Comment: У меня почему-то не получается пройтись им :(

Comment: Значит надо написать конкретный вопрос: у меня есть вот это, надо сделать это, я пытаюсь сделать вот так, но как результат получаю вот это. чяднт

Comment: Как минимум тут явно что-то не указано... указаны функции, а внутри  функции применяется синтаксис для методов, свойств класса

Comment: @SemyonBayandin зачем мне это делать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский прошу прощения, не вас хотел выбрать

Comment: @jjjjj забейте в гугл "php foreach"

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что вам нужно проходиться по двухмерному массиву не зависимо от наименования ключей записей(Все записи). Это можно реализовать через цикл foreach. Что-то типо этого:

```
public function dispatch() {
  foreach ($this->routes as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
      // здесь можно выполнить какой-то код для каждого маршрута, например:
      // $route->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Тут я предположил что написанный здесь вами пример является одним из методов общего класса. Соответственно $this->routes Это поле с двухмерным массивом. Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)